# Removing boundary quote from a JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, string

i want to remove the boundary qoute and the escaping character that is present inside the json.
here is my JSOn tha look like

```
"[{\"Type\":\"String\",\"isList\":true,\"Name\":\"nametwo\"},{\"Type\":\"String\",\"isList\":false,\"Name\":\"namethree\"}]"
```

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
var jsonString = "[{\"Type\":\"String\",\"isList\":true,\"Name\":\"nametwo\"},{\"Type\":\"String\",\"isList\":false,\"Name\":\"namethree\"}]";
var o = jQuery.parseJSON( jsonString );
```

Comment: Or, without jQuery: JSON.parse(jsonString) (if IE >= 8)

Comment: this removes the backslash but not the boundary qoutes

Comment: this is the result in console:  o[0]
Object {Type: "String", isList: true, Name: "nametwo"}; o[1]
Object {Type: "String", isList: false, Name: "namethree"}